# 'GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl

How do I fix this? I've got both gl/gl.h, and gl/glu.h included, so what gives?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"It''s part of OpenGL 1.2, which is why it isn''t in Microsoft''s OpenGL 1.1 header.

Add this line to your code somewhere. BTW, you should probably check the GL version at runtime before using it.

```
#define GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE 0x812F
```

"

I just googled it and found [this](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/191794-gl_clamp_to_edge---non-existing/).  Does it help?